# Kotlin class instance assertEqual

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm new to java / kotlin. I would like to assert equality on the following class:

```
class PlaceCommand(vararg args: String) : ICommand {
    var direction: Direction = Direction.valueOf(args[1].toUpperCase())
    var x: Int               = args[2].toInt()
    var y: Int               = args[3].toInt()

    // ...
}
```

What change is required to turn:

```
class FactoryTest {
    @Test
    fun testFactorySuccess() {
        val args = arrayOf("place", "WEST", "1", "1")
        val a    = PlaceCommand(*args)
        val b    = Factory(args) as PlaceCommand

        Assert.assertTrue(a.x.equals(b.x))
        Assert.assertTrue(a.y.equals(b.y))
        Assert.assertTrue(a.direction.equals(b.direction))
    }

    // ...
}
```

Into something like:

```
class FactoryTest {
    @Test
    fun testFactorySuccess() {
        val args = arrayOf("place", "WEST", "1", "1")

        Assert.assertEqual(PlaceCommand(*args), Factory(args) as PlaceCommand)
        # or
        Assert.assertTrue(PlaceCommand(*args).equal(Factory(args) as PlaceCommand))
    }

    // ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: btw, using `vararg` in this case seems like a terrible idea. You gain nothing and loose the type information you could otherwise have

Comment: I agree with how you see it. Take a look at the code: https://github.com/jamesmoriarty/kotlin-robot/blob/master/src/test/CommandFactoryTest.kt

Comment: all looks pretty normal, except for `Command` factories. I cannot imagine a reason for internal use of an array of strings, then converting it into typed values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `equals` method on PlaceCommand

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean{
    if (this === other) return true
    if (other?.javaClass != javaClass) return false

    other as PlaceCommand

    if (x != other.x) return false
    if (y != other.y) return false

    return true
}
```

If you use Intellij Idea you can press `Alt+Insert` to generate it.

Then just use `==` operator to test for equality

`Assert.assertTrue(PlaceCommand(*args) == (Factory(args) as PlaceCommand))`

In kotlin `==` is equivalent to `a?.equals(b) ?: b === null`. `===` is reference equality